# Percentage of time employee schedules align with supervisor schedule

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, overlap, schedule

Utilizing the data provided to you, please construct an Excel Workbook containing the following:

A tab containing the following information:
Employee ID
Working formulas to depict:
Name
Shift Type
Detailed hours of Shift start time/end time
New Supervisor
New Senior Manager
Title
Alignment Percentage with Supervisor (must be a working formula)
Counts of Employees per Supervisor
A tab containing a pivot table with the following information:
Count of workgroups by
SM Team
Supervisor Team
Employee
Grand Total of employees by workgroup and Grand Total
Color coding of Total Count per supervisor teams based on thresholds:
Supervisors with <11 employees on Team: Green
Supervisors with 12 to 13 employees on Team: Yellow
Supervisors with >14 employees on Team: Red
A tab containing the following information:
A pivot table detailing the count of all employees per Workgroup
A working formula depicting the actual ratio of Representative to Supervisor.
Color coding of ratio based on thresholds
Ratio of <11 employees on Team: Red
Ratio of 12 to 13 employees on Team: Yellow
Ratio of >14 employees on Team: Green[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYCZM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuZkd.png)

Comment: Homework I'm guessing. Have a go and you might learn something. If you are stuck on a specific issue, post your code and show where you are having difficulty.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"<"&MIN(B2:B6)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUND((MAX(C2:C6)-MIN(B2:B6))*1440,0)))/1440-1/2880,C2:C6,">"&MIN(B2:B6)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUND((MAX(C2:C6)-MIN(B2:B6))*1440,0)))/1440-1/2880)>0)+0)/60

Comment: I have this ready to go my question is this code is comparing two separate columns. How would I compare more than two columns at a time in one formula?

Comment: @CJN "compare more than two columns at a time in one formula?" <--- from column A to P which column did you mean? about 'compare' is it to change for duplicates, find total, find same row same data count.. or something else??... can you give some examples.? Appreciate if you can share the sample file/data + A sample case/scenario for others to replicate.